# Using simplejson module to dump usernames as an array

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, simplejson, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to implement bootstrap typeahead in django. In my template file, I want a textbox for users to enter text [usernames in my case]. The approach I am shooting for is to have django provide an array `user_json` to `show.html`, so bootstrap typeahead could use that array.

In my views.py file I have added the following function:

```
def users_list_json(request):
    users = User.get_username()

    user_json = simplejson.dumps(users)
    render_to_response("show.html", {"user_json": user_json})
```

But when I run console.log(user_json) in show.html it throws an error (ReferenceError: user_json is not defined). How should I go about implementing this? Is there an easier way?

I want an array with all the usernames to be available in show.html file so I could use that with typeahead.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant portion of the show.html template, as well as the relevant portion of the rendered page?

Comment: Could you add an error to your question? It will be very helpful to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the function a bit.

```
def users_list_json(request):
    user_list = [u.username for u in User.objects.exclude(username=username)]
    context.user_json_list = simplejson.dumps(user_list)
```

And, I called the array in show.html by adding:

`{{ user_json_list|safe }}`